# Specifying solution build order in the MonoDevelop

Tags: build-process, monodevelop, projects-and-solutions

I have a C# solution being developed with MonoDevelop, there are a number of projects.
When the solution is being built, I need to make sure some project A is built after some other project B in the same solution.
I can add reference to project B into project A, that's called Project-To-Project reference. This approach does not fit my requirements as B's output gets copied into A's target folder. So, I can not use P2P reference.
According to this, http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Solutions_and_Projects_explained, solution file (*.sln) supports "specifying build order".

Can anyone provide me with any info on how I can specify projects build order on the solution level, without using P2P references?

TIA

Comment: The question is still open. But I have found workaround that meets my requirements. Now I use usual P2P reference and set its "Local Copy" property to False (in the P2P ref's Properties dialog). The effect is the following: project A is built after project B and output of B is not copied into A - exactly what I need.